# JPA: @ManyToOne, unnecessary duplicate Entries in 1 Table

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa

I have a dealersearch, where distributors are persisted. Data of dealers like street, name, phone number and so on will be imported somehow via excel files.

**In my database I need meta-data about the imports of dealer data.**

I use **spring-boot-starter-jpa**.

### My models:

Import (metadata of the import[-process] itself)

- datetime
- status (successful/failed)
- numberOfDealers imported
- tenant (dealers of what brand/country e.g. Volkswagen in USA)
- environment (what servers: production, test, dev)

Tenant

- brand (Audi, Volkswagen, Seat)
- market (country where the distributor is located)

Import and Tenant are connected. Each Import includes one Tenant. One tenant Id appears multiple times in the Import table. Each Tenant in the Tenant table consisting of brand and market/country should be unique.

Data rows example, **how it should be**:

### Import

id - datetime - environment - numberOfDealers - status - tenant_id

1. 2016-04-17 - DEV - 122 - successful - 1
2. 2016-04-17 - DEV - 40 - successful - 2
3. 2016-04-19 - DEV - 130 - failed - 1
4. 2016-04-22 - LIVE - 1044 - successful - 3

### Tenant

tenant_id - brand - market

1. A - KOR
2. A - ARG
3. A - USA

**How it actually is**:

### Tenant

tenant_id - brand - market

1. A - KOR
2. A - ARG
3. A - KOR
4. A - USA

The relationship is correct, but Tenant has duplicates, **KOR was entered twice**.

### My Java Models

```
@Entity
public class Import {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "import_id")
private Long id;

private String datetime;

private String status;

private Integer numberOfDealers;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "tenant_id")
private Tenant tenant;

private String environment;

public Import() { }

public Import(String datetime, String status, Integer numberOfDealers, Tenant tenant, String environment) {
    this.datetime = datetime;
    this.status = status;
    this.numberOfDealers = numberOfDealers;
    this.tenant = tenant;
    this.environment = environment;
}

/*getters and setters here*/

}
```

---

```
package com.dasburo.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
//@Table(uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"market", "brand"})})
public class Tenant {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "tenant_id")
private Long tenantId;

private String market;

private String brand;

public Tenant() { }

public Tenant(String market, String brand) {
    this.market = market;
    this.brand = brand;
} 

/*getters and setters here*/

}
```

---

```
for (Import anImport : imports) {
    importDao.save(anImport);
}
```

imports is an array of Import objects filled with data, including a tenant

The use of uniqueConstraints annotation does only set the structure of the table 'Tenant', but not the behaviour. JPA still tries to do duplicate entries in the 'Tenant' table.

Comment: "JPA" persists the objects that you pass to it. If you give it a new Tenant object then you get a new one in the datastore.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, if you're loading an already existing schema and creating entities based on existing tables then the unique constraint present in your schema should cause an exception when the duplicate happens. However if you're creating tables from your entities then you cannot rely entirely on annotations to force the unique constraint, as stated in JPA wikibooks:

> Some expect the JPA provider to have magic that automatically
>   maintains relationships. This was actually part of the EJB CMP 2
>   specification. However the issue is if the objects are detached or
>   serialized to another VM, or new objects are related before being
>   managed, or the object model is used outside the scope of JPA, then
>   the magic is gone, and the application is left figuring things out, so
>   in general it may be better to add the code to the object model.
>   However some JPA providers do have support for automatically
>   maintaining relationships.